# Convert Composite Video to RS-422

Tags: dac, video, differential-amplifier, rs422, ntsc

### I misinterpreted my requirements and asked the question below, which does not make sense.

I am designing a Digital (TMDS/HDMI) to Analog (Composite) video circuit. I am almost to the end. The last step is to convert the composite video (which follows the RS-170 guidelines) to differential RS-422 signals. I am currently using Analog's ADA4433-1, to convert my composite signal to differential. Composite is as follows: White is +1V, Black: +.075V, Blank:0V, and Sync is -.4V. I know RS-422 is +/- 6V.

I am basically trying to convert composite video to RS-422(TIA/EIA-422) differential pair and I am looking for IC's to do this, reference schematics, or ideas.

Comment: Please only ask one question, this is very similar to the last question you asked. It would be great if you could pick one question and delete the other. Also, editing the question is preferable to opening a new one. Please also ask a specific question, and not ask for a reference.,

Comment: RS-422 cannot support composite video bandwidth, let alone HDMI. Also RS-422 transceivers only operate on digital inputs and outputs. So you have two problems. RS-422 transceivers won't produce a balanced analog output. You would need to design a single-ended to differential output circuit with op-amps. And then a differential to single-ended circuit on the other end. Forget the RS-422 specifications.

Comment: Way too many misconceptions in one question. None of this makes sense. We need to explain literally every technical term you use considering you seem to misuse it - voting to close as too broad. Please take a lot of steps back. Ask one question, and one question alone, and **very** clearly state when you're making an assumption.

Comment: Marcus, thank you will do! There was a misconception.

Comment: @VoltageSpike thank you, I am new to using stack exchange, I'll figure it out though. Also, this is my first go around doing Video DAC and ADC.  I have only 5 days of experience trying to figure this out. I will get better though, this video stuff is interesting.

Comment: @miggyEE no worries a good idea is to look at the help center for asking questions https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Answer (score 2):

What you seek is impossible or mistake in the specs.

RS-422 is a digital data interface. It can't carry analog video.

Last step of converting something to analog video such as composite is the analog video. There should be no need to think how to convert analog video to RS-422 which is an electrical spec for transmitting digital data. They are unrelated and incompatible, so there is no way to convert analog composite video to RS-422 in any meaningful way.

If by 422 you happen to mean digital YCbCr video with 4:2:2 subsampling, typically sent over BT.656 kind of parallel interface, that's not analog video but digital and still does not relate to RS-422.

Comment: Hello Justme, you are correct. We are using a connector that has RS-422 but also has other signal interfaces on the connector/cable. I misunderstood my requirement thinking that the signals have to RS-422. Thank you for the clarification. I am converting the BT.656 to Composite using the ADV7393. I guess since that is clarified, and if you may, what do you think of using the ADA4433-1 to convert the composite signal to differential and output over the rf cable?

Comment: I don't know what you need to do and why but at least  it looks like you are following datasheet suggestions.

Comment: okay thanks, Ima delete the question know. Never mind, I wont, I guess its not good to delete it.